# Call inherited method from its base class

Tags: c#, .net

I have an abstract class which is used to derive dozens of other classes, each class do similar but slightly different things. These class are loaded by Reflection and exposed to the user, to choose which one he needs to run.

This work because the base class has an abstract method called Run which is override by each derived class. So everywhere in the code where I need a variable of any of these types, I declare them as the base class. Then when I call the Run method, it executes the method from the real type (even though I declared it as the base class).

My problem is that I need to show a customized UI for each of these derived classes. I thought to make a custom UserControl to each one. These controls would have a puclic method that returns me a value based on what the user did on it. Then I create this control at runtime, the user sets what is needed and I call the return method from this control and I can finally pass i to the Run Run method from the class the user chose and execute it.

I don't know how many or which derived classes I have because the user can create dll derived from that base class and attach it as a plugin.

Because of this I think I would have to create these custom controls on the form as the generic UserControl class and then cast them as the real type. But is there any way of doing that only knowing that the control was derived from UserControl?

I can create a public property on the base class to store its custom control, but back at the main code can I cast the generic user control as the type stored in this property?

Also, would be a design problem here? Could I use another approaches to do that?

I hope it does not sound very confusing :(

Comment: Are there existing plugins? (i.e. do you need to worry about backward-compatibility?)

Comment: It is more than possible and you are on the right track - using generics you can avoid a lot of the casting issues (look at Generic Constraints) and allow the user to define the UI of the usercontrol (they would need to point the ascx at a class they had created which used your Generic Base class as the template)

Comment: Can't you simply require your user controls to implement an interface?  Then you can know ahead of time what method to call to get the data.

Comment: @Tejs using generics does offer less casting/unboxing issues (I like to think of them as a templating mechanism) but yes you are of course correct he could use the classic interface technique

Comment: @Cameron, Nope, I don't need to worry about backward compatibility.

Comment: @TEjs, I could try with interfaces, gotta learn a little bit more about them first. I'll post the results or solution as soon as I get one...

Answer (score 3):

I might have misunderstood you, but this is what I'm thinking:

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> where T: UserControl, IMyControl
{
    private Page _page;
    protected T Control { get; private set;}

    public BaseClass(Page page, string controlPath)
    {
        _page = page;
        Control = (T)page.LoadControl(controlPath);
        _page.Controls.Add(Control);
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        var data = Control.GetData();
    }
}

public interface IMyControl
{
    object GetData();
}
```

Comment: I tried to use your code, but the System.Windows.Controls.Page doesn't have a LoadControl method. Only  the System.Web.Ui.Page has. Since I'm already working with System.Windows namespace, would be any harm to mix both?

Comment: If I understood your code, I  must create a page inside the window (which will show my user controls), then I'll pass this page reference to my base class, which will load the control on that page Object. Right?

Comment: Yeh, this code example is for web app, since you didn't specify. But im sure you can use the same principle for a win forms app.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a class which inherits from UserControl. I don't think you can make it Abstract, but you can create a method on your other type called CreateControl() which will return an instance of that UserControl that should contain the UI.

You can then add that UserControl to a Panel, or some other container without actually caring about what specific UserControl it is. If there are specific methods you'll want to have that UserControl to implement, like Save or Load, then you can add those as virtual methods in your Base class which derives from UserControl.

Comment: I thought on that, but then on my abstract base class I'll this method will have to return a UserControl type, because the base class doesn't know the derived control name. Since I'm calling all methods from the base class, I won't have a way to access the CreateControl method from the UserControl type. Is my thinking right?

Comment: Why does the base class need to know the derived control name?

Comment: Because it needs to call a method that only exists in the derived control. Or maybe is there a way to call the method on the derived class?

Comment: It really shouldn't be necessary for your code to call a method that only exists on the derived control. If there is certain logic that is specific to the derived control, then its likely to be an event handler which can be contained completely within the derived control. If the Derived Control needs to do things to the object that created it, then it should have an internal reference to that object, and do that internally as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the correct or best solution, but based on the above answers and some research I solved the problem this way:

Each class derived from the BaseClass has an overridable method GetControl. This method return a new instance of the UserControl designed specifically for the class.

When the user choose a derived class, I call the GetControl method and I add this control do the form. Then the designed UI for the class is shown. This control is removed if another class is pick and the new UI is then created for this other class.

To read the setup the user made in the control, I implemented a method called ReadData on each UserControl. To call this method from the Object level, I used reflection:

```
Object ui = FindControlByName("SelectedClassUI");
Type t = ui.GetType();
MethodInfo m = t.GetMethod("ReadData");
Object userSetup = m.Invoke(ui, null);

<... do something with userSetup ...>
```